# Initialize gocql ips using a constant

Tags: go, gocql

I need to initialize gocql with multiple ips, I want to pass the ips from a variable/constant.

How to pass some thing like

```
gocql.NewCluster(ipvalues)
```

instead of using

```
gocql.NewCluster("127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.2")
```

i want to pass the list of ips through a variable something like an array.

Comment: A constant cannot be an array or a slice, but that's actually unrelated to the core of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can [see](https://godoc.org/github.com/gocql/gocql#NewCluster), `gocql.NewCluser` takes a variadic parameter, which means you can pass multiple values separated with commas to the function.

In go, you just need to make your `ipvalues` variable be a slice of strings and pass it like this:

```
ipvalues := []string{"127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.2"}

gocql.NewCluster(ipvalues...)
```

This will have the same effect as writing `gocql.NewCluster("127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.2")`

See [the golang spec for more information on this feature](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)